# Create a Navigation Panel in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, menu, navigation

I did this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

I'm trying to implement this for have a slide-out menu to replace the center view controller:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=19064&start=40#p85001

Here my code of the modificated files, I've taked the finally project to be sure:

CenterViewController:

```
@objc
protocol CenterViewControllerDelegate {
  optional func toggleLeftPanel()
  optional func toggleRightPanel()
  optional func collapseSidePanels()
}

class CenterViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak private var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak private var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak private var creatorLabel: UILabel!

    var delegate: CenterViewControllerDelegate?

    // MARK: Button actions

    @IBAction func kittiesTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.toggleLeftPanel?()
    }

    @IBAction func puppiesTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        delegate?.toggleRightPanel?()
    }
}
```

ContainerViewController:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

enum SlideOutState {
  case BothCollapsed
  case LeftPanelExpanded
  case RightPanelExpanded
}

    class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, CenterViewControllerDelegate, SidePanelViewControllerDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {


  var centerNavigationController: UINavigationController!
  var centerViewController: CenterViewController!

  var currentState: SlideOutState = .BothCollapsed {
    didSet {
      let shouldShowShadow = currentState != .BothCollapsed
      showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow)
    }
  }

  var leftViewController: SidePanelViewController?
  var rightViewController: SidePanelViewController?

  let centerPanelExpandedOffset: CGFloat = 60

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    centerViewController = UIStoryboard.centerViewController()
    centerViewController.delegate = self

    // wrap the centerViewController in a navigation controller, so we can push views to it
    // and display bar button items in the navigation bar
    centerNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: centerViewController)
    view.addSubview(centerNavigationController.view)
    addChildViewController(centerNavigationController)

    centerNavigationController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)

    let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
    centerNavigationController.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
  }

}

// MARK: CenterViewController delegate




extension ContainerViewController: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate {
    func itemSelected(item: MenuItem) {
        let vc = item.viewController()
        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Menu", style: .Plain, target: self, action: "toggleLeftPanel")
        self.centerNavigationController.viewControllers = [vc]
        self.collapseSidePanels()
    }
}

extension ContainerViewController: CenterViewControllerDelegate {

  func toggleLeftPanel() {
    let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .LeftPanelExpanded)

    if notAlreadyExpanded {
      addLeftPanelViewController()
    }

    animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)
  }

  func toggleRightPanel() {
    let notAlreadyExpanded = (currentState != .RightPanelExpanded)

    if notAlreadyExpanded {
      addRightPanelViewController()
    }

    animateRightPanel(shouldExpand: notAlreadyExpanded)
  }

  func collapseSidePanels() {
    switch (currentState) {
    case .RightPanelExpanded:
      toggleRightPanel()
    case .LeftPanelExpanded:
      toggleLeftPanel()
    default:
      break
    }
  }

  func addLeftPanelViewController() {
    if (leftViewController == nil) {
      leftViewController = UIStoryboard.leftViewController()
      leftViewController!.animals = Animal.allCats()

      addChildSidePanelController(leftViewController!)
    }
  }



    func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {
        sidePanelController.delegate = self
    }

  func addRightPanelViewController() {
    if (rightViewController == nil) {
      rightViewController = UIStoryboard.rightViewController()
      rightViewController!.animals = Animal.allDogs()

      addChildSidePanelController(rightViewController!)
    }
  }

  func animateLeftPanel(#shouldExpand: Bool) {
    if (shouldExpand) {
      currentState = .LeftPanelExpanded

      animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) - centerPanelExpandedOffset)
    } else {
      animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { finished in
        self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

        self.leftViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.leftViewController = nil;
      }
    }
  }

  func animateCenterPanelXPosition(#targetPosition: CGFloat, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)! = nil) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
      self.centerNavigationController.view.frame.origin.x = targetPosition
      }, completion: completion)
  }

  func animateRightPanel(#shouldExpand: Bool) {
    if (shouldExpand) {
      currentState = .RightPanelExpanded

      animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: -CGRectGetWidth(centerNavigationController.view.frame) + centerPanelExpandedOffset)
    } else {
      animateCenterPanelXPosition(targetPosition: 0) { _ in
        self.currentState = .BothCollapsed

        self.rightViewController!.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.rightViewController = nil;
      }
    }
  }

  func showShadowForCenterViewController(shouldShowShadow: Bool) {
    if (shouldShowShadow) {
      centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
    } else {
      centerNavigationController.view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    }
  }

}

extension ContainerViewController: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
  // MARK: Gesture recognizer

  func handlePanGesture(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight = (recognizer.velocityInView(view).x > 0)

    switch(recognizer.state) {
    case .Began:
      if (currentState == .BothCollapsed) {
        if (gestureIsDraggingFromLeftToRight) {
          addLeftPanelViewController()
        } else {
          addRightPanelViewController()
        }

        showShadowForCenterViewController(true)
      }
    case .Changed:
      recognizer.view!.center.x = recognizer.view!.center.x + recognizer.translationInView(view).x
      recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: view)
    case .Ended:
      if (leftViewController != nil) {
        // animate the side panel open or closed based on whether the view has moved more or less than halfway
        let hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x > view.bounds.size.width
        animateLeftPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway)
      } else if (rightViewController != nil) {
        let hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway = recognizer.view!.center.x < 0
        animateRightPanel(shouldExpand: hasMovedGreaterThanHalfway)
      }
    default:
      break
    }
  }
}

private extension UIStoryboard {
  class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

  class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
  }

  class func rightViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
  }

  class func centerViewController() -> CenterViewController? {
    return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? CenterViewController
  }

}
```

SidePanelViewController:

```
import UIKit

protocol SidePanelViewControllerDelegate {
    func itemSelected(item: MenuItem)
}

class SidePanelViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  var delegate: SidePanelViewControllerDelegate?

  var animals: Array<Animal>!

  struct TableView {
    struct CellIdentifiers {
      static let AnimalCell = "AnimalCell"
    }
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.reloadData()
  }

}

// MARK: Table View Data Source

extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
  }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(TableView.CellIdentifiers.AnimalCell, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AnimalCell
    cell.configureForAnimal(animals[indexPath.row])
    return cell
  }

}

// Mark: Table View Delegate

extension SidePanelViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        let selectedAnimal = animals[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.itemSelected(MenuItem(rawValue: indexPath.row)!)
    }
}

enum MenuItem: Int {
    case Home
    case Animals
    case Settings

    func viewController() -> UIViewController {
        switch (self) {
        case Home: return {
            let vc = UIViewController();
            vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
            return vc
            }()
        case Animals: return UIStoryboard.centerViewController()!
        case Settings: return {
            let vc = UIViewController();
            vc.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor();
            return vc
            }()
        }
    }
}

class AnimalCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var animalImageView: UIImageView!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageNameLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var imageCreatorLabel: UILabel!

  func configureForAnimal(animal: Animal) {
    animalImageView.image = animal.image
    imageNameLabel.text = animal.title
    imageCreatorLabel.text = animal.creator
  }

}


private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard { return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()) }

    class func leftViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
    }

    class func rightViewController() -> SidePanelViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as? SidePanelViewController
    }

    class func centerViewController() -> CenterViewController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CenterViewController") as? CenterViewController
    }

}
```

When I run and I slide the left or right menu, it's slinding a black window instead of the menu.

Comment: Try to use the least amount of code where this problem occurs

Comment: Can you share your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing few lines in your `ContainerViewController.swift`,  `addChildSidePanelController` function

```
func addChildSidePanelController(sidePanelController: SidePanelViewController) {
    sidePanelController.delegate = self

    /*** Missing Lines Start ***/
    view.insertSubview(sidePanelController.view, atIndex: 0)

    addChildViewController(sidePanelController)
    sidePanelController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    /*** Missing Lines End ***/
}
```

Comment: It's look good, i'm gonna do different storyboard and put a link on them (because now I'm just doing a background color), i'll come back to you if I get an error :)

Comment: Excuse me, do you know why I lost my delegate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524590/delegate-is-nil-cant-open-my-slide-out-menu